Dapper One-To-Many, Multi mapping with several lists
I'm having some difficulties expanding the provided example "One-To-Many" on https://www.learndapper.com/relationships
My use case is as follows, on a blazor SSR page I need to retrieve a single project including nested objects based on a ProjectID provided as a [Parameter] on this page.
The complete structure I need to retrieve looks like this:

Project

 1:n ProjectFase                 



   1:n ProjectItem



      1:n ProjectItemDate



         1:n Appointment



A single Project contains no, 1 or more ProjectFase
A single ProjectFase contains no, 1 or more ProjectItem
A single ProjectItem contains no, 1 or more ProjectItemDate
A single ProjectItemDate contains no, 1 or more Appointment
The Project class looks like this (I removed some fields for clarity):
public class Project
{
    public string ID { get; set; } //PK

    public List<ProjectFase>? Fases { get; set; } = new List<ProjectFase>();
}

public class ProjectFase
{
    public int ID { get; set; } //PK

    public string ProjectID { get; set; } //FK

    public List<ProjectItem>? Items { get; set; } = new List<ProjectItem> { };
}

public class ProjectItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; } //PK

    public int? ProjectFaseID { get; set; } //FK

    public List<ProjectItemDate>? Dates { get; set; } = new List<ProjectItemDate> { };
}

public class ProjectItemDate
{
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; } //PK, FK

    public int? ProjectItemID { get; set; } //FK

    public List<Appointment>? Appointments { get; set; } = new List<Appointment> { };
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int ID { get; set; } //PK

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

}

On the project page I retrieve the project by:

    [Parameter]
    public string ProjectID { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        project = await _db.GetProjectById<Project, dynamic>(ProjectID, new { projectid =    "projectid", faseid = "faseid" });

    }

GetProjectById is a method inside my DataAccess layer, and this method looks like this:
public async Task<Project> GetProjectById<T, U>(string ProjectID, U parameters)
{
    string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);
    string sql = "select p.ID as projectid, f.ID as faseid, f.Name as fasename from dbo.Projects p INNER JOIN dbo.ProjectFase f ON p.ID = f.ProjectID WHERE p.ID  = '" + ProjectID + "' ";

    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try 
        {
            var projects = await connection.QueryAsync<Project, ProjectFase, Project>(sql, (project, fase) =>
            {
                project.Fases.Add(fase);
                return project;

            }, splitOn: "faseid");

            var result = projects.GroupBy(p => p.ID).Select(g =>
            {
                var groupedProject = g.First();
                groupedProject.Fases = g.Select(p => p.Fases.Single()).ToList();

                return groupedProject;  
            });

            return result.FirstOrDefault();

        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            
        }

        return null;
    }
}

This all works like a charm and i'm able to retrieve a single project object with multiple fases, but now I want to add the next levels (ProjectItem, ProjectItemDate, Appointment) to this object but can't seem to get it right, how can I achieve this?
Note: I was able to retrieve the desired result by using a lot of foreach loops per object/level but given the amount of data this look 4-5 seconds on big projects so this approach won't work for me.
I could really use some pointers here

Dapper is great, but not intended to do this kind of operations.

If you are trying to populate the lists of objects within each level of each object, you better off creating an independent data access for each object with either SQL injection or Stored procedures. You can then call all of these into an intermediate method which will populate these lists per layer. Populating the entire project object by looping through everything is going to be much more costly, and you cannot really run them asynchronously as you have to wait for each itiration to complete.
For example: populating the project object
var Project = Data.ReadAllProjectFasesByProjectIdAsync(id);

IEnumerable<Task> PopulateProject()
{ 
   foreach(var x in Project.Fases) 
      yield return Task.Run(() => ReadAllItemsByProjectFaseIdAsync(id); 
}
await Task.WhenAll(PopulateProject());

You can repeat the same process for each inner object. Just take note to have all your data access methods (e.g. ReadAllProjectFasesByProjectIdAsync) to be asynchronus so that all this populating can be truly async.
